# Registered users should be authenticated only once

Tags: php, android, mysql, authentication

guys i am working on android 2.2.I have a situation where when the user enters the application  he will allowed to use the default audio file provided.

Now there is a button when he clicks on it will go to login page.If he is not a registered user he can register himself and again login with the username and password.Once he logins with his username and password he will be allowed to download n number of audio files from the server.

So what i want to acheive is once the user is a registered user and logins and exits the application but again if the registered user wants to download some more files he should not be prompted with username and password since he is a registered user.

How to acheive this?

Code to login the registered user:

```
ArrayList<NameValuePair> nvp = new  ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

             nvp.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userid", userid.getText().toString()));
             nvp.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password.getText().toString()));
             String un = userid.getText().toString();
             String pass = password.getText().toString();

             System.out.println("user name is " + un);
             System.out.println("password is " +pass);
//           Log.e(""+sid.getText().toString(),"0"); 
//           Log.e(""+sname.getText().toString(),"0");
                try {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://mywebsite.com/login.php");
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvp));
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                is = entity.getContent();
                } catch(Exception e){
                    Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection"+e.toString());
                }
                try {
                    BufferedReader bf  = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
                    sb = new StringBuilder();
                    sb.append(bf.readLine()+ "\n");
                    String line="0";
                       while ((line = bf.readLine()) != null) {
                                      sb.append(line + "\n");
                        }
                        is.close();
                        result=sb.toString();
                    System.out.println("value of result " +result);

                    if(result.contains(auth)){

                        System.out.println("username and password is correct");

                        Intent authorised = new Intent(Login.this,BrowseFiles.class);
                        startActivity(authorised);
                    }else{

                        System.out.println("incorrect wrong wrong wrong");
                        error.setText("Incorrect username and password");
                    }


                }catch(Exception e){
                      Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [SharedPreference](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) for your application and check it when you starts downloading .if it is setted then you can continue otherwise open Login/registartion page whatever you want

EDIT:
Once user is successfully login

```
SharedPreferences share_pref=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
      SharedPreferences.Editor editor = share_pref.edit();
      editor.putBoolean("Login", true);

      // Commit the edits!
      editor.commit();
```

then before downloading you can check this boolean value if it is true then do downloading else go to login screen

Comment: i need to store username and password? can you please give me any example on that

Comment: refer the link it will show an example also to use sharedPreference and show how to edit also

Comment: You just need to edit when user is authenticated and check it before downloading the content on button press....

Comment: What do mean by 'You just need to edit when user is authenticated' sorry i didnt get you

Comment: Sorry. I think u have not got my problem.Once the user is a registered user i dont him to login again he can directly download the files so only once the registered user will be logged in

Comment: yes i understand what you want that's why i suggest you to use sharedPreference because it will remain until you are not uninstall the app from phone

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8619/discussion-between-deepak-sharma-and-goofy)